# How to have AWS VPC subnets associate with one Route Table in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I have a Terraform file that is supposed to create an AWS VPC remotely. In doing so, it would create 3 Public Subnets and 3 Private Subnets. There would then be one Route Table for each group of public and private subnets. My current configuration has it so that a route table is created for EACH subnet. I'm also having a similar issue with NAT Gateways and Public Subnets; I only want one NAT Gateway for all Public Subnets.

These are the pertinent blocks from my `main.tf` file:

```
//Creating Public Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "publicsubnets" {
  provider          = aws.east
  count             = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  vpc_id            =  aws_vpc.Main.id
  cidr_block        = "${var.public_subnets[count.index]}" //CIDR block of public subnets
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zones[count.index]}"
  tags = {
    Name = "publicsubnets"
  }
}

//Creating Private Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "privatesubnets" {
  provider          = aws.east
  count             = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  vpc_id            =  aws_vpc.Main.id
  cidr_block        = "${var.private_subnets[count.index]}" //CIDR block of private subnets
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zones[count.index]}"
  tags = {
    Name = "privatesubnets"
  }
}

//Creating Route Table for Public Subnets
resource "aws_route_table" "PublicRT" {
  provider = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  vpc_id   =  aws_vpc.Main.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "IP_Addresses" //Traffic from Public Subnet reaches Internet via Internet Gateway
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.IGW.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "publicRT"
  }
}

//Creating Route Table for Private Subnet
resource "aws_route_table" "PrivateRT" {
  provider = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.Main.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "IP_Addresses" //Traffic from Private Subnet reaches Internet via NAT Gateway
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.NATgw[count.index].id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "privateRT"
  }
}

// Associate Public Subnets with Route Table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PublicRTassociation" {
  provider       = aws.east
  count          = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.publicsubnets[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.PublicRT[count.index].id
}

//Associate Private Subnets with Route Table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "PrivateRTassociation" {
  provider       = aws.east
  count          = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.privatesubnets[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.PrivateRT[count.index].id
}

//Associate Elastic IP's to Public Subnets
resource "aws_eip" "nateIP" {
  provider = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  vpc      = true
  tags = {
    Name = "nateIP"
  }
}

//Associate Public Subnets to NAT Gateways
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw" {
  provider      = aws.east
  count         = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nateIP[count.index].id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.publicsubnets[count.index].id
  tags = {
    Name = "NATgw"
  }
}
```

I have provider and variables declared in separate files.
Note: I have changed some names for security/privacy reasons.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating NATs in a loop. If you want to use single NAT gateway, you need to create only one NAT gateway resource (without a loop).
Something like below:

```
resource "aws_eip" "nateIP" {
  provider = aws.east
  vpc      = true
  tags = {
    Name = "nateIP"
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "NATgw" {
  provider      = aws.east
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nateIP.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.publicsubnets[0].id
  tags = {
    Name = "NATgw"
  }
}
```

Then, in your route table, you'd set NAT like below:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "PrivateRT" {
  provider = aws.east
  count    = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.Main.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "IP_Addresses" //Traffic from Private Subnet reaches Internet via NAT Gateway
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.NATgw.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "privateRT"
  }
}
```

However, having a single NAT has its downside. Your infrastructure would be reylying only on one availablity zone for NAT. In case there are issues with that Availability zone, your application may have issues.